# Why isn't the size specifier working in my FORTRAN inquire statement?

Tags: file-io, fortran, fortran2003

I am trying to work with FORTRAN INQUIRE and the relatively new SIZE specifier, and getting some curious results.

My test code:

```
program howbig


integer :: fsize=0
logical  ex

character*64 :: fname='fmtdata'

print *,fsize

open(unit=15,file=fname)
inquire(unit=15,size=fsize, exist=ex)
print *,fsize, ex
close(15)

inquire(file=fname, size=fsize, exist=ex)

print *,fsize, ex

end program
```

The file 'fmtdata' exists and has a size of a few bytes:

```
> ls -l fmtdata
-rw-rw-r-- 1 tklim  tklim 6 Jan 28  2011 fmtdata
```

I compile with Portland Group:

```
> pgf90 howbig.f9
```

Here are the results of a few test runs:

```
> ./a.out
            0
            1  T
   -827850024  T
> ./a.out
            0
            1  T
  -1422197528  T
> ./a.out
            0
            1  T
    876874792  T
> ./a.out
            0
            1  T
   -107620360  T
```

So, I obviously don't get the file size, and I don't even get the same output each time.  Any ideas what is going on?  I should say that my rev. of pgf90 is fortran 95 compliant, with some 2003 features available.  I would have thought that if this 2003 feature was not working, it wouldn't have compiled.  Thanks.

Comment: Looks like a compiler bug to me.

Comment: Yes.  It works with gfortran 4.7 and ifort 12.1.

Comment: When manipulating files in Fortran, you may be interested in my [modfilesys](http://aradi.bitbucket.org/modfilesys/) wrapper around libc's file system functionality, especially the [filesize()](http://aradi.bitbucket.org/modfilesys/classfilesys__module.html) function in it. You'll, however, need a compiler with F2003 features as C-interoperability and allocatable scalars.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, guys.  I like compiler bugs.  They make me feel less stupid.  @Balint: Thanks for the code!